# How do I breed a Malachite dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I have heard reports of the Malachite dragon not being in the shop but being a possible new dragon introduced with the Pollen Dragon.

Is this a gem dragon? (isn't malachite technically a mineral??)

Comment: Malachite is an ore of copper. It's green and [looks pretty nifty](http://images.wikia.com/geology/images/b/b7/Malachite.jpg).

Comment: @James, yeah I can see the metal connection - I'm a little looser on the plant connection (other than that it is green).

Comment: It is like the _Blue Fire_, _Frostfire_, _Current_, and _Plasma_ Dragons, in the sense that it is a hybrid of two opposing elements, with the same look as one of the dragons (_Metal_) but coloring based on the other (_Plant_). It seems reasonable to expect a _Plant_ / _Metal_ hybrid at some point, with the color of the _Metal_ dragon, but the body of a _Plant_ dragon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to breed a plant dragon with a metal hybrid as the [Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Malachite_Dragon) says. Apparently it is important that the metal dragon is the hybrid one, as there are several similar pairings between incompatible dragons where choosing which dragon is the hybrid determines which breeding result you can get.

Note you can't directly breed a plant and metal dragon; alone they are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

To get a malachite dragon you have to breed a metal and poison. I got it on my first try.